Proof that $PREFIX_{TM}$ is not recognizable
We define $PREFIX_{TM}$ as the following language:
$PREFIX_{TM} = \{ \text{ <M> | M is a TM, L(M)}\neq \varnothing \text{ and whenever M accepts w it accepts every prefix of w} \}$
We only learned about $\overline{A_{TM}}$ and $\overline{HALT_{TM}}$ as unrecognizable lagnagues so I probably need to reduce one of them to $PREFIX_{TM}$ in order to prove that $PREFIX_{TM}$ is unrecognizable
Here's the reduction I thought about so far (It isn't good):
for $<M,w>$ where $w=c_1c_2c_3\dots c_n$ create a turing machine $M'$ such that $M'$ accepts every prefix of w. $M'$ also accepts each word in the form of $z = c_1c_2c_3\dots c_{n-1}r$ where $r\in \Sigma^*$ and $r\neq c_n$, and in addition to that it accepts
the word $c_1c_2c_3\dots c_n c_n$.
For the word w, $M'$ simulates $M$ (with w as input). And for every other word it rejects.
Now, $M'\in PREFIX_{TM} \iff w \in M$
But actually I need $M'\in PREFIX_{TM} \iff w \notin M$
(since I am trying to reduce $\overline{A_{TM}}$ to $PREFIX_{TM}$

Reduction from the halting problem. Given a Turing machine $M$, we let $M^*$ denote a Turing machine which operates as follows. First, it rejects every input which is not the empty word. Secondly, when the empty word is give as input, it simulates the computation of $M$ and accepts iff $M$ halts. Now $M$ halts iff $M^*$ is in your language.

But he needs the language to be unrecognizable. M* needs to accept the empty word iff M does not halt.
